# How do I use multiple Query hooks from redux-toolkit in the same component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

So in redux toolkit you're able to create hooks that call to a RestApi using multiple endpoints, I'm using 3 endpoints which using redux-toolkit it creates 3 hooks that I can use anywhere in my react application, my question is how do I get it to work all in one component?

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useGetCountryQuery, useGetRegionQuery, useGetAllQuery } from "../../services/CountryAPI";
import CountryCard from "./CountryCard";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const CountryList = () => {
  const { option } = useSelector((state) => state.option);
  const { data = [], isFetching } = useGetAllQuery();
  const { data = [], isFetching } = useGetCountryQuery();
  const { data = [], isFetching } = useGetRegionQuery(option);

  return (
      <>
          {data.map((country) => (
            <Link onClick={() => {}} key={country.name.official} to={`/details/${country.name.official}`} >
                <CountryCard
                    key={country.name.official}
                    name={country.name.official}
                    capital={country.capital}
                    region={country.region}
                    population={country.population}
                    flag={country.flags.svg}
                />
            </Link>
        ))}
    </>
);
};

export default CountryList;
```

As you can see I have to destructure "data" and "isFetching" for all three hooks which is how I know functions, What is an alternative way for me to use all three API hooks so i can use it on the same component being "CountryCard" I want to display?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For one, you could decide to just not destructure.

```js
  const allResult = useGetAllQuery();
  const countriesResult = useGetCountryQuery();
  const regionResult= useGetRegionQuery(option);

  return (
      <>
          {countriesResult.data?.map((country) => (
```

Or, you rename things while destructuring:

```
  const { data: all = [], isFetching: allFetching } = useGetAllQuery();
  const { data: countries = [], isFetching: countryFetching } = useGetCountryQuery();
  const { data: regions = [], isFetching: regionFetching } = useGetRegionQuery(option);
```

Comment: Thank you this solved my issues, Keep up the amazing work!!